# Can a Jinja template variable be accessed by index position, if the index position value is defined within a variable?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask to build a Web APP that is going to display the average values of several columns for a list of persons.

Let´s say I have 4 fields `(field1,field2,field3,field4)` and several rows of information for those 4 fields for every person on a list of persons.

I calculate the averages for each field and for each person and store them in a variable called `averages`, which is a list of lists. Each item of  the variable `averages` is a list that contains the average for each field for one specific person

So, for example:

`averages = [[5,6,5,4],[2,3,4,5]]`

Contains the average of `field1,field2,field3,field4` for two persons, each person represented by a list within the list of lists which is `averages`.

I hope it is clear so far...

Now the Flask part.

When I render the template, I pass averages as variable:

`return(render_template("display_averages.html",averages=averages))`

From the "Template Designer Documentation" of Jinja

*You can use a dot (.) to access attributes of a variable in addition to the standard Python **getitem** “subscript” syntax ([]).*

So I can do, this: `{{ averages.0.1 }}`, and based on the example below where the variable `averages` contains the following values:`averages = [[5,6,5,4],[2,3,4,5]]`

`{{ averages.0.1 }}` will be substituted by `6` as it is the element 1 in the list 0

So far so good, but what I want to achieve is to have a counter in the template: `{% set person_counter = 0 %}` and use that `person_counter` to access the items in the averages variable.

So what I would have done to achieve it, would have been:

{{ averages.person_counter.0 }}

But it does not work, it does return error:

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected name or number

I know that I can do:

```
{% for average in averages %}
{{average}}
{% endfor %}
```

To iterate over the elements of the list averages, but that is not what I want to achieve.

My specific question is

Can I somehow use a Jinja variable as an index variable for accessing another Jinja variable which is a list?

I think the issue is well explained.

What other options do I have for achieving something like what I have asked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`averages.0.1` is the same as `averages[0].1` (or even `averages[0][1]`), however the second version also supports variables.

In your case the following should work:

```
{{ averages[person_counter].1 }}
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#variables

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly the answer I was looking for.