# How to access list items in django jinja template dynamically using variable indexing

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

## Django jinja template error - TemplateSyntaxError

I was trying to create sample show users page where I am want to show username, password and role of the users. I will be storing role as numbers and later I am trying to get the role name from a list.

I have hard coded this role names to a list `roles = ['admin', 'teacher', 'student']`
this roles has been passed to html page as context value. Also, I am passing a num variable for accessing the list items(atm its value is also hard coded, I will be changing this in future)

#### views.py

```
def index(request):
   roles = ['admin', 'teacher', 'student']
   num=1
   return render(request=request, template_name='show_all.html', context={'roles': roles, 'num': num})
```

and inside my html page I am trying to access this list using `num` variable as given below

#### show_all.html

```
{{roles[num]}}
```

###### but it is throwing an error

> **TemplateSyntaxError at /show_all** 
> Could not parse the remainder: '[num]' from 'roles[num]'

there are few solutions that saying `roles.0` will get you the first result and `roles.1` will give next, But I don't want to hard-code the index there.

##### requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.5.2
Django==4.1.3
sqlparse==0.4.3
tzdata==2022.6
```

I have tried

```
{{roles.num}}
```

```
{{roles.get(num)}}
```

```
{{roles[num]}}
```

nothing is giving me desired result.

Comment: Why not index in the view itself and pass to jinja

Comment: @ilyasbbu that's exactly what I proposed in my solution.

Comment: that will work here, but I am having some plans to implement this using list. So the num variable will be changed to a list. so here something similar to this solution is needed, like some kind of jinja methods or anything that works inside jinja.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149694/can-a-jinja-template-variable-be-accessed-by-index-position-if-the-index-positi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach:

```
def roli(roles, i):
    """Return the rol[i]"""
    return roles[i]
```

In Jinja:

```
{{ roles|roli:i }}
```

I would recomend you to read the documentation about `tags`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/ you need some extra steps to register the template tag.

Other approach.
A workaround could be the following:

```
def index(request):
   roles = ['admin', 'teacher', 'student']
   num=1
   return render(request=request, template_name='show_all.html', context={'roles': roles, 'num': num, 'rolesi': roles[num]})
```

And then:
show_all.html

```
{{rolesi}}
```

Comment: Yes thar will work. But acutally I dont want to change the python code there. Instead I wanted to have this on the jinja template. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: In my case I will be implementing a database. And will be storing roles of users to a table along with some other fields. So that final data(taking only roles as list) will be looking like model_roles=[1,2,1,3], I will put a loop through this list and based on the current index I will be printing the role_name there. Have tried putting if condition in jinja. But it might not be scalable. So I just wanted to get something that will be scalable 

Comment: @Harikrishnan.A.S- review the updated answer...

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you so much, also as you mentioned in the answer, I had to look through, setting up the `Custom template tags and filters`. Thanks a lot for looking into this issue.